# Creating an EV SSL certificate for local usage

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am currently working on a small website. To make it look more legitimate and professional I'd like to have a green lock with my name on it in the browsing bar (EV SSL certificate). Have 2 .pem files for normal and EV SSL certificates created. The thing is: I don't know how to continue. I searched through like 50 threads on several forums including StackOverflow and haven't found anything really useful. Something was said about modifying the openssl config [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641962/how-do-i-create-my-own-extended-validation-certificate-to-display-a-green-bar), but I really don't know how the thread creator got these flags so I didn't even try them because they probably won't work anyways. 
I'd really appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate a certificate self-signed or signed by your own CA which is treated as EV certificate by unmodified browsers. Certificates are marked as EV by having  OID in the certificate which are specific to the issuing certificate authority. Which authorities can issue EV certificates and which OID they use is hard coded into the browsers, i.e. you would need to change the source code and recompile the browsers to accept EV issued by your own CA.

For more information see [Can I build my own Extended Validation SSL certificate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48053/can-i-build-my-own-extended-validation-ssl-certificate) or [How to generate self-signed EV SSL Certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84765/how-to-generate-self-signed-ev-ssl-certificate).

Comment: It "works" because the OID to use depends on the CA hence the browser checks both the CA and the presence of a specific OID. For example for Mozilla based ones: https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/mozilla/IncludedCACertificateReport