# how to create Green lock SSL Certificate for website?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate

i heard about Ev #SSL certificate more security for [website](https://www.mediaspotstudio.in) and generated and installed free #SSL #Certificate but its not showing Name in Green Lock, anyone can help me ?

Comment: This makes no sense: if you read and understand what an EV certificate is then you should understand that  a  free SSL certificate is not an EV certificate. See also [Creating an EV SSL certificate for local usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792079/creating-an-ev-ssl-certificate-for-local-usage).

Comment: There are no free EV certificates available. EV means "[extended validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)" and you have to pay the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, no one is providing EV SSL certificate at free of cost in the market. So the certificate which you have installed may be standard or basic ssl certificate.

[image]

Second thing is that, EV SSL certificate doesn't display name in the green lock but it displays your business / organization / company name in the browser next to green padlock. If you still have confusion regarding to understand between standard ssl and ev ssl certificate, then you should read this resource https://www.tech-wonders.com/2018/09/why-ev-ssl-is-better-compared-to-standard-ssl.html where you will find in detailed information about EV SSL & how it differs from the standard ssl.